# Auction contract execution error

Tags: contract-development

I am building an auction smart contract in Remix with random winners being picked.
And I am not getting any value out of the following function:

```
 }
    function revealWinners() public {
        for (uint id = 0; id <3; id++) {
            Item storage currentItem=items[id];
            if(currentItem.itemTokens.length != 0) {
                uint randomIndex = (block.number /
                currentItem.itemTokens.length)% currentItem.itemTokens.length;
                uint winnerId = currentItem.itemTokens[randomIndex];


            }
```

Everything else is working as it should but I have been stuck on this for a while, anyone here have an idea what I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

To fulfill your requirement may be `returns` may solve it.

```
  function revealWinners() public returns (uint) {
        for (uint id = 0; id <3; id++) {
            Item storage currentItem=items[id];
            if(currentItem.itemTokens.length != 0) {
                uint randomIndex = (block.number /
                currentItem.itemTokens.length)% currentItem.itemTokens.length;
                uint winnerId = currentItem.itemTokens[randomIndex];
                return winnerId;
        }
    }
 }
```

**update:**

---

If you want to return any value from the function then  you have to use `return` keyword as other programming language do . As you see in the function

> function revealWinners() public returns (uint){

you have to use returns(data_type_Or_datatype_with_name) in the function.
so  the function have to be like this:-

> function functio_Name(agr1,agr2,..) returns (ret_arg1,ret_arg2,..){
>   //logic here
>    return(ret_arg1,ret_arg2,..)
>   }